# How to apply jQuery rule except if it is inside an element with certain class?

Tags: jquery

Sample HTML code:

```
<div class="foobar" ...>
<div class="subelem" .....>
<figure>. first figure....</figure>
</div>
</div>
<figure>. second figure....</figure>
```

Now I want to remove all  elements which are NOT (!) inside an element with a class=foobar

If I code this with jQuery:

```
$("figure").remove();
```

then ALL  elements are removed.

How can I restrict the removal to only  elements OUTSIDE of element with a class=foobar?

In the sample code above only the second figure should be removed

Be aware the element with class=foobar need not to be the direct parent element of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update your selector.

```
   $("figure:not(.foobar figure)").remove();
```

Comment: Hi @pstein if you find this answer correct, please mark it as the right answer, Thanks.